# How to get the normalized form of a lambda expression?

Tags: python, lambda, inspect

I need [Church encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_encoding#Inc) of numbers for some purpose, so I define the numbers as follows:

```py
# Let's define zero
zero = lambda f: lambda x: x

# A successor function
successor = lambda n: lambda f: lambda x: f(n(f)(x))

# Now I can define any number inductively/recursively
one = successor(zero)
two = successor(successor(zero))
```

Now, if I try to print the source of `one`, `two`, etc., the full expressions are not reduced to their normal forms:

```py
import inspect;
print(inspect.getsource(zero))
print(inspect.getsource(one))
print(inspect.getsource(two))
```

Output:

```
zero = lambda f: lambda x: x
succ = lambda n: lambda f: lambda x:  n(f)(x)
succ = lambda n: lambda f: lambda x:  n(f)(x)
```

How can I see the reduced form where the body of the innermost lambda for `one` and `two` is reduced to the [normalized form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus_definition#Normalization) (evaluated?) i.e. I can tell the difference between the reduced expressions `one` and `two`.

As a reference, an equivalent form of `one` and `two` could be as follows:

```py
zero = lambda f: lambda x: x
one = lambda f: lambda x: f(x)
two = lambda f: lambda x: f(f(x))
```

But I can't get the same differentiation from `inspect.getsource`. Of course, I don't want a verbatim equivalency, but something that still is able to show the different nesting levels in `one` and `two`.

Comment: Python *doesn't have lazy evaluation*. You can reproduce lazy evaluation using iterators/generators. But Python is eagerly evaluated. In any case, `inspect.getsource` is not going to get you anything, it relies on the actual source code.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case, you can pass a new lambda function as an argument to `one` or `two` that returns a string with the correct stacking level. However, it does not give you the form of the lambda inputs (`lambda f: lambda x:`).

```
zero(lambda x: f'f({x})')('x')
# returns:
'x'

one(lambda x: f'f({x})')('x')
# returns:
'f(x)'

two(lambda x: f'f({x})')('x')
# returns:
'f(f(x))'
```